# Publishing linear referencing capability in ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, linear-referencing

I created a linear referencing event and want to publish as linear referencing service in ArcGIS 10.2 for Server . The problem is when i want to publish, High warning shows the linear referencing event table not recognized .in other hand the linear referencing item in capabilities not found .

How can i publish the linear referencing service?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the Roads and Highways extension for Server to publish a map service with linear referencing capability.

See here for an [overview of this extension in version 10.2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Esri_Roads_and_Highways_for_Server_overview/02230000004t000000/).